# rails 4 gem install error using homebrew-installed gcc compiler

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I am installing gem sqlite3 for rails 4 and get a compilation error. This is a completely new macbook pro with Mavericks OS installed. I have installed XCode, but then also installed gcc 4.9 using Homebrew (using instructions [here](http://www.computersnyou.com/2673/2013/10/install-ruby-rails-macos-x-mavericks-10-9-mysql-step-step/)). Everything was going smooth until I started getting a compilation error while trying to install the gem sqlite3:

```
    app_folder git:(mybranch) gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for sqlite3.h... yes
    checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
    checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
    checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
    checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
    checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
    checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... no
    checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... no
    checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
    checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
    checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
    checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
    creating Makefile

    make "DESTDIR="
    compiling backup.c
    gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wshorten-64-to-32'
    make: *** [backup.o] Error 1
```

Upon doing some research of the issue, I have found little information besides that this command line option is mac-specific and Homebrew-installed gcc compiler does not have it! Is there a way for me to switch back to native mac gcc compiler? How do I resolve this and why is it barely mentioned anywhere?

```
    gcc -v
    Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-       include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
    Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

I just installed Rails and had a similar experience. I fixed it by getting osx to recognize the correct g++ version and then reinstalling ruby. Here are a few suggestions:

1. You can set your gcc and g++ version via .bash_profile with the following code

   ```
   export CC=gcc-4.9
   export CXX=g++-4.9
   export CPP=cpp-4.9
   ```

   check your g++ version with g++ -v. If this doesn't work you may need to do bit of hacking.
2. Per http://instantbadger.blogspot.com/2011/11/porting-rails-23-app-to-ruby-19.html, you can remove the default g++ in /usr/bin and substitute it with a new symlink to g++-4.9:

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++.bak && sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/g++-4.9 /usr/bin/g++
   ```

   Note: this command is different from the one present in the linked page (which moves /usr/local/bin/g++). I didn't have a copy of g++ in /usr/local/bin/, so I adapted the command to work with /usr/bin instead.

   Check g++ -v again. It should now reflect the correct version of g++.

Once your g++ version checks out, you can try reinstalling ruby. This insures that your ruby version is compiled with the same compiler that your going to build your gems with.

```
    rvm install 2.0.0
```

Once you've done that, repeat

```
    gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'
```

Hopefully, this should work now.